# c++ value losing value after loop

Tags: c++

I have the following problem when compiling and executing the following code:
inside the while loop, x1 keeps it value. Once "ok" is entered and the while loop is finished, x1 looses its value and is reset to 0.

Can you tell me what causes this?

ps. I know about vectors and tables, but not using them atm.
Using dev c++ to compile

```
int main(){
        int x1 = 10; int x2=10,x3=10;
        int y1=60,y2=20,y3=20;
        string res="";
        cout << "config x pos ";
        cin >> res;
        while(res != "ok"){
            cin >> res;
            x1= atoi(res.c_str());
            moveTo(x1, y1);
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << x1;
        cout << "config y pos ";
        cin >> res;
        while(res != "ok"){
            cin >> res;
            y1= atoi(res.c_str());
            moveTo(x1, y1);
            cout << endl;
            cout << "x " << x1 << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it moves the cursor to those coordinates.

Comment: I tried removing that line from the first loop, but x1 still is 0 after the loop

Comment: From what do you conclude that `x1` looses its value after the loop? (First or second loop, btw?) The only time where you inspect `x1` is in the second loop, the last line. Maybe the problem is how you print `x1`?

Comment: Too many `cin >> res` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well once you enter "ok" and break the loop,
the function atoi(res.c_str()) return zero into the variable x1;

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot the input was read after the check, which indeed gives 0 as a result.
thank you!

Comment: Yeah , the atoi function ignores any kind of characters except numbers. for example atoi(5x) will return 5.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter 'ok' from the console, the next line to execute is

```
x1 = atoi(res.c_str());
```

When faced with a non-numeric string, atoi returns 0, which is then assigned to x1. Thus x1 will always be zero when you're loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you do `cin >> res` twice at the start (once before the loop and then as the first line of the loop copy). Change your loop to:

```
while ( (cin >> res) && (res != "ok") )
{
    x1= atoi(res.c_str());
    moveTo(x1, y1);
}
```

You might also want to think about doing something more intelligent than `atoi`, e.g. this will just move to 0 if they type in "hello" and so on.